# ADSL modem with Tplink router and local server

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router, webserver, modem

I am starting to learn how to mount local server for django apps, i recently bought an small server running ubuntu 14.04, gunicorn and nginx to serve django apps, but i already have a pc as server to share files and some windows applications. I have a adsl modem vigor2710e/ne and a tplink tp-wr841n wireless router. On the adsl modem i have three computers connected to a local network, the fourth connection goes to the router and in the router i have other two computers connected. If i access through the server app ip(e.g 192.168.1.101) on the computers connected to the router the django application loads well but if i try to access to that ip from the computers on the adsl modem the app doesn't load. I think that the ip adresses of the router should be given by the adsl modem, or maybe use the router as a switch, but i'm not sure if i'm kind of right. Anyone can explain me to learn and also help me to solve this?

Comment: Is the modem connected to the router in the wan/Internet port.

Comment: yes, i connected the modem to the router wan port.

Comment: Plug the modem to the lan port of the router. But change the IP address of the router to something within the same ip of the modem. In essence you are just extending your network and not layering.

Comment: thanks it worked, i did something like: the modem has the ip 192.168.1.10, then i assigned the 192.168.1.11 to the router and disabled dhcp and then the other connected devices goes from 192.168.1.12 and works fine but sometimes on the computers connected to the router assings ip like the modem one(192.168.1.10) and also in some weird cases an ip like 169.254.24.104 and when this happens i lost the internet connection in the other devices. Why is that?

Comment: The IP starting with 169.x.x.x usually means that windows cannot find the DHCP to assign an IP, so it just gave it one. Ensure your distribution of IP address has a sufficient range to handle every device connecting.

Answer (score 0):

By what you are telling me, the modem is also acting like a router. In essence what you want to do is extend your network using the 2nd router. 
So here are the steps you'll need to take:

1. On the modem ensure that DHCP is enabled.
2. Assign the distribution of IP address range to something like 192.168.1.100 to 192.168.1.199 in the DHCP. This will give you up to 100 connections.
3. Reboot the modem.
4. On the router disable the DHCP
5. Change the IP address of the router to something within the same IP of the modem. So if you have IP address of the modem to 192.168.1.10 then change the IP address of the router to 192.168.5.11 for example.
6. Reboot the router
7. Plug the modem into one of the LAN ports of the router.
8. Turn off your devices prior to connecting to router and modem
9. Plug your devices into the router and modem.
10. Turn on your devices
11. Check to ensure you devices are getting IP addresses from the DHCP

Here is a good article [How to Connect One Router to Another to Expand a Network](http://www.wikihow.com/Connect-One-Router-to-Another-to-Expand-a-Network)

Comment: thanks, i'll check that, so the dhcp has to be disabled on the router and in the modem i have to increase the ip pool counts to avoid to get the 169.x.x.x addresses assigned to the devices in the router or in the modem? because the ip pool count on the modem is set to 50 so i have from 192.168.1.10 to 192.168.1.60 but i checked the connected devices and the  assigned ip's and  i only had up to 192.168.1.30.  I also fixed one ip with mac adress to the server to avoid it to change and be accesible from the others computers connected to the modem and de router (eg. 198.168.1.12), that affects?

Comment: this are the steps that i followed: first i checked the ip addresses range on the modem, it displays: 192.168.1.10 and ip pool count to 50, then i opened the configuration of router, there i assigned the ip 192.168.1.11, i left the ssid of the router as default instead of naming it like the ssid modem, after that i disabled the dhcp on the router and it restarted, after that i plugged the LAN 1 of modem to LAN 1 of router, the lan of server to LAN 2 of router then power on the router, and waited to windows equipments to detect the ip and works fine.

Comment: also my internet connection was failing and there's where i think that the ip addresses change to 169.x.x.x so i had to reset the modem and the router.

Comment: or if i connect e.g. a TL-SF1005D, it's a basic switch instead of the router it will do the same job?

Comment: Make sure your ip address pool does not contain the IP addresses of your router and modem. Start the pool at something higher like .50 to .100.

Comment: i fixed the router IP by mac on the modem, it's that ok? my modem is 192.168.1.10 and the router is 198.168.1.11, and i bind it in modem with router mac address.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help GeekyDaddy, the solution that seems to work was to increase the IP pool count from 50 to 150 and i think that now is working fine. I lost the internet connection a few times on the computers connected to the router but them reconnected automatically without assigning the 169.x.x.x IP.

Also, it's normal that works fine increasing the IP pool count, because i only have 10 computers in total connected to the network and to internet? With 50 it should work fine, right?